# Javascript: Parse each CSV column to separate JSON

Tags: javascript, csv

I am using **csvtojson** npm library, and i read options, but cannot figure out, how can i make separate json files from CSV columns.

The CSV format is :

```
invoiceNumber;taxNumber
test-1;00000000
test-2
```

for options i am using: `{columns: false, delimiter: ';'}`

and the output is :

```
{ invoiceNumber: 'test-1', taxNumber: '00000000' }
{ invoiceNumber: 'test-2' }
```

however the expected output is :

```
{ invoiceNumber: 'test-1'}
{ taxNumber: '00000000' }
{ invoiceNumber: 'test-2' }
```

Is it possible with any csv parser npm library?

Comment: Very odd requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this task, I recommend using lodash. After csttojson try this script

```
const _ = require('lodash')

const arr = [{ invoiceNumber: 'test-1', taxNumber: '00000000' },
{ invoiceNumber: 'test-2' }];
console.log(_.flatMap(arr, item=>_.map(_.toPairs(item), d => _.fromPairs([d]))))
```